# Water simulation on rain water harvesting

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I am currently working on a science project about water harvesting and I was asked to make a simulation of rain and then it colliding with the pipes and getting collected in a tank although I made it look like rain by using a simple particle system I made a separate fluid sim with mostly the default setting for the pipes here is a picture:-
[image] 
so the question is how do I make it look like water simply flowing in a pipe ?
cause it doesn't look like water flowing through pipes

I also tried changing the mesh to a cylinder-ish thing
[image]

Comment: Where do you want the water to come from? How should it behave? How much should the pipe get filled with water?

Comment: Your flowing water sim would have to be a lot larger so that the water drops condense into a finer mesh. Have you considered modelling the water as a curve object then animating its curve length?

Comment: What 3pointedit said plus it looks like your pipes have volume as volume initialisation. You should change it to shell. To be true it probably would be better to use particle system with Fluid physics and emitting metaballs to achieve what you need.